# vue.js Mount component to app root

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a modal.vue component as follows:

```
<template>

    <transition name="modal-transition">
        <div class="modal-body" v-if="displayed">
            <div class="modal-overlay" @click="displayed = false"></div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <slot/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>

</template>
```

How do I mount this component to the applications root element rather than in place?

For crude inaccurate example:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="stage">
       <div class="sub-nav"></div>
       <div class="content">
          <modal :display.sync="display">MY MODAL</modal> <-- Don't mount here...
       </div>
    </div>
    <-- Mount here instead...
  </div>
</body>
```

The current issue is that my sites header and navigation is layered on top of my modal and it's darkened full screen overlay instead of layered behind the modal overlay.

[image: Header and Navigation on top]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Vue 2

Move the elements own self to the element of applications root may be achieved in two ways, Using a portal as a preferred solution or using an append.

**Using a Portal (Preferred Method)**

> PortalVue is a set of two components that allow you to render a
> component's template (or a part of it) anywhere in the document - even
> outside the part controlled by your Vue App!

https://portal-vue.linusb.org/

---

**Using an Append (Not best practice)**

If adding a portal library is too heavy, using an append is allowed but lightly discouraged officially in the VUE docs.

Typically this particular mount position will satisfy a z-index overlay for your own modal or dialog popup that you require to render over the top of the entire app. You can always substitute **this.$root.$el** in this example for a different element target using standard **getElementBy** or **querySelector** functions.

Here the element is being moved not destroyed and re-added, all reactive functionality will remain in tact.

```
<script>

    export default {

        name: 'modal',

        ...

        mounted: function() {
            this.$root.$el.append(this.$el);
        },

        destroyed: function() {
            this.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$el);
        }
    }
</script>
```

On **mounted** the element is moved inside of where the top level VUE app instance is mounted.

On **destroyed** removes the placeholder DOM comment for the migrated component from the new parent to prevent orphaned duplication each time the component remounts it's self.
VUE officially states not to destroy an element outside of VUE so this is not to be confused with that statement, here the component has already been destroyed.

This DOM comment duplication will typically happen when for example switching views with vue-router as this mechanism mounts and dismounts all components in a router view  each time vue-router view state changes.

This behaviour is a bug cause by vue-router, the object is destroyed properly by VUE render manager but an index reference remains by mistake, using a portal package resolves this issue.

Here is the result:

[image: Header and Navigation underneath!]

Comment: removing dom elements directly especially if it is of a component is a big no no in vue.

Comment: Do you have any information to back this claim?
What negative impacts are there if any at all?
You have not provided any information in assisting with this problem.
Still researching this issue thus why it's not the accepted answer, VUE Portal packages must be doing a similar thing. After doing some more tests there appears to be no memory issues, UI glitches or stacked binds, don't forget that VUE under the hud is interfacing with native JS functions as I have done.
VUE already destroyed the relevant event binds and data but failed to clean up an empty comment <!----> for the place holder

Comment: Read on reactivity in depth section of vue.

Comment: I’m not saying it’s illegal, but what I’m implying is it’s a very bad practice. Vue promotes data-driven approach which means you should avoid meddling with vue’s render system which includes manually destroying elements that are referenced and managed by vue

Comment: However there are certain cases that it cann’t be avoided like using non-vue third party plug-ins particularly jquery plugins.

Comment: I had a read and spent days looking for an "approved method" or way to pre-declare the dom mounting position, Only possible solution I found was creating vue instance templates using "el" option to specify where to mount, however it seemed like a terrible path having a large amount of content and contradicts VUEs original concept besides adding layers of complications, like having to use a HUB for data exchange, just to fix a tiny z-index edge case issue seemed too ridiculous, plus coding all that would bloat the performance... 
Current method I used appears not to have broken any reactivity.

Comment: Was using vue-material md-dialog that has an md-portal wrapper to create own vue instance but has a lot of event bridging going on. Anyway something was hurting my eyes when looking at dialog content, days later noticed md-dialog content has slightest of blurring because they used fixed 50% with negative position transform trick to centre in the screen, that trick causes a minute blur.
That lead me to investigating to the above conclusion after I wrote my own replacement that uses a flex-box overlay to justify content in the centre of the screen =  Zero blur. Eyesight saved...

Answer (score 7):

### Update for Vue 3

There is now a built in feature called [teleport](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html#teleport) which allows mounting parts of your component template to any DOM element.

The example from the OP would look like something like this

```html
<!-- MyModal.vue -->
<template>
    <transition name="modal-transition">
        <div class="modal-body" v-if="displayed">
            <div class="modal-overlay" @click="displayed = false"></div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <slot/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- SomeDeeplyNestedComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <teleport to="#app">
        <!-- Can still receive props from parent -->
        <MyModal :my-prop="foo">
           <!-- slot content -->
        </MyModal>
    </teleport>
</template>
```

Comment: Awesome, very simple solution!